# Substring Charindex help to extract (T-SQL)

Tags: substring

How would I get the last section after the last "/"?

/{ct6yr356-051t-55e2-b89r-546454ab922}/location/Missouri/costcenter/TXX1/Sales Orders on Queue.rdl

Sales Orders on Queue <-- The part I want to extract. There are always six of '/' and .rdl at the end.

The language is T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Got what I needed.

> ;WITH R as (
>         SELECT '/{ct6yr356-051t-55e2-b89r-546454ab922}/location/Missouri/costcenter/TXX1/Sales
>   Orders on Queue.rdl' as VARIABLE
>        ) SELECT SUBSTRING(VARIABLE, START, 
>                    CHARINDEX('.rdl', SUBSTRING(VARIABLE, START, LEN(VARIABLE)))-1
>                   ) FROM  (SELECT CHARINDEX('/', R.VARIABLE,
>           CHARINDEX('/', R.VARIABLE,        CHARINDEX('/', R.VARIABLE,      CHARINDEX('/', R.VARIABLE,      CHARINDEX('/', R.VARIABLE) +1) +1) +1)
>   +1) + 1 as START, R.*
>         FROM R
>        ) R